# jQuery "show" until element doesn't have inline style

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Ok, so given this HTML structure:

```
<li></li>
<li style="display: none;"></li>
<li style="display: none;"></li>
<li style="display: none;"></li>
<li style="display: none;"></li>
<li></li>
```

So what i need is a jQuery selector that when hovering over the first `li`, it "shows" the next four `li`'s because they have `display:none` on and then doesnt have any effect on the last `li` because it doesnt have `display:none` on it

Comment: @AbeMiessler Nothing, i'm interested if you can select an element without style...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many ways to do this, one of which is:

```
$('li:first').hover(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('li:not(:hidden)').show();   
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`.nextAll('li:hidden')` will do the job, you can use it like this:

```
$('li').hover(function(){
    $(this).nextAll('li:hidden').show();
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8VRex/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul > li:first').hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings().show();
});
```

You can see it working in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XDNM7/